# WP7 background agent database access

Tags: database, windows-phone-7, background, agent

I'm a beginner programmer in C#, so I think that the solution of my question might be easy, but after looking for it for days, I have not found anything that worked for me.

I have a WP7 app that contains a DB created with SQL CE.

CLASS PorniBD.cs

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace PhoneClassLibrary1
{
    [Table(Name = "Papilleros")]
    public class PorniBD
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
        public String Nombre { get; set; }
        [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
        public String FechaNac { get; set; }
        [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
        public Boolean Activo { get; set; }
        [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
        public String Icono { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CLASS PorniContext.cs

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.Data.Linq;

namespace PhoneClassLibrary1
{
    public class PorniContext : DataContext
    {
        public PorniContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
        {
            //
        }

        public Table<PorniBD> Papilleros
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<PorniBD>();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My app has a background agent created in another project like I have learned in this page: [Link](http://jesseliberty.com/2011/10/05/background-agents/)

Now, I need to read app DB from background agent, and this class contains following OnInvoke void:

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
        {
            List<PorniBD> listapapilleros = new List<PorniBD>();
            using (PorniContext basedatos = new PorniContext("Data Source='isostore:/basedatos.sdf'"))
            {
                listapornis = basedatos.Papilleros.ToList();
            }

            // Launch a toast to show that the agent is running.
            // The toast will not be shown if the foreground application is running.

            ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            NotifyComplete();
        }
```

but it's impossible because DataSource isolated is different in each project (I think), and I suppose that it's necessary to fix something more...

Thanks a lot for your help, and sorry if my English level is makes my explanation a bit difficult to understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a third project, of type "Windows Phone Class Library". Move your database code in that third project, then reference it from both your main project and your background agent project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer KooKiz. But when I create the third project, there is a problem in "using" line of OnInvoke void. The error is related to ToList() function of DataContext: it's impossible to call it (I don't know why, because when I use toList() from app project the call is correctly working). (see code updated in my original message)

Comment: @user2723183 Make sure you have the line `using System.Linq;` on top of your file